# Return a django user that is in two models' many-to-many fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Node(models.Model):
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

I would like to get all users that are node collaborators and also a project collaborator, assuming I have the pk of the node. What query would I need for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F
User.objects.filter(node__pk=node.pk, project=F('node__project'))
```

That *should* work. Haven't tested it. If not, you can try this one as well:

```
User.objects.filter(node__pk=node.pk, project__node__pk=node.pk)
```

Assuming they *both* work, you might want to try both in something like [django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar)'s `debugsqlshell` management command to see what kind of query each produces and which might be more efficient.